# Get last 24 hours from selected date using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run sub-query first to get specific date, i then want to use that date as starting point to get the last 24 hours from that date.  Here is the query i want to run first as sub-query

```
select ID, FullDatetime from myTable 
where selectedDate = 0900 and DT = CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

i then want to use the result from above query to generate the last 24 hours from the selectedDate.  Please note all data are in the same table.  I want to run another query that gives me the last 24 hours from the selectedDate above.  The data type for the FullDatetime is datetime.  Please help.  thanks

Comment: Use DATEDIFF() or DATEADD()

Comment: What have you tried? Is `SelectedDate` a string or a numeric type that you want to compare to 900? (So many questions about the last 24 or 48 hours in Military Time.)

Comment: `declare @Id as VarChar(42); declare @FullDateTime as DateTime; select @Id = ID, @FullDateTime = FullDatetime from myTable 
where selectedDate = 0900 + 0 and DT = CONVERT(date, getdate()); select ... where ...;`? Or do you want to `JOIN` your "subquery" to allow multiple results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ID, dateadd(hh, -24, FullDatetime) from myTable  /* or (dd, -1, ...) */
where selectedDate = 0900 /* did you mean '0900'? */
    and DT = CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

I suspect you could also avoid the query entirely by calculating it directly:

```
select dateadd(hh, -15, {fn current_date()})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery twice to get the date you are using to base your filter date on:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE datevalue BETWEEN (SELECT TOP 1 selectedDate FROM myTable WHERE a = b) 
 AND DATEADD(hh, -24, (SELECT TOP 1 selectedDate FROM myTable WHERE a = b))
```

Comment: thanks but i need to run the subquery first and use the selectedDate from the subquery as starting point to generate the last 24 hours as i posted in my initial post